How to call server action from client Nextjs14?
I know that server action can be invoked by by submitting a form when I use 'use client' directive but how to execute a sever action automatically
when the page loads .
When I load a page I have an id and then I want to execute a server action which loads details of a given person for eg his name, location,phone number etc  which depends on id from sqlite3 database .
Can some one give a working example for this scenario .
Where Things are going wrong ?

export function getMeal(meal){
    return db.prepare('SELECT * from meals WHERE id=@id').get(meal);
}

'use client';
import {useSearchParams} from 'next/navigation';
import {useFormState} from "react-dom";
import {updateMeal} from "@/lib/action";
import classes from "@/app/add/page.module.css";
import {useState} from "react";
import {getMeal} from "@/lib/meals";


export default function UpdateExisting() {

    const searchParams = useSearchParams()
    const id = searchParams.get('id');

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getDataFromServerAction() {
            const data = await getMeal(id);
            console.log(data);
        }
        // Call the above function
        getDataFromServerAction();
    },[])




Write the server action in a different location mostly inside the action file which has  'use server' directive added on top of it .  And then call the getDataFromServerAction() method inside useEffect . This worked for me
 'use server'
 async function getDataFromServerAction() {
            const data = await getMeal(id);
            console.log(data);
        }


'use client';
import {useSearchParams} from 'next/navigation';
import {useFormState} from "react-dom";
import {updateMeal} from "@/lib/action";
import classes from "@/app/add/page.module.css";
import {getDataFromServerAction} from "@/lib/action";
import {useState} from "react";
import {getMeal} from "@/lib/meals";


export default function UpdateExisting() {

    const searchParams = useSearchParams()
    const id = searchParams.get('id');

    useEffect(() => {
       getDataFromServerAction().then()
    },[])



